# tensor division in pytorch. Assertion error

Tags: pytorch, division

This is kind of a pytorch beginner question. In pytorch I'm trying to do element wise division with two tensors of size [5,5,3]. In numpy it works fine using np.divide(), but somehow I get an error here. I'm using PyTorch version 0.1.12 for Python 3.5.

c = [torch.DoubleTensor of size 5x5x3]

input_patch = [torch.FloatTensor of size 5x5x3]

input_patch is a slice of a torch.autograd Variable, and c is made by doing c = torch.from_numpy(self.patch_filt[:, :, :, 0]).float()

When doing:

```
torch.div(input_patch, c)
```

I get this error that I don't understand.

```
line 317, in div
assert not torch.is_tensor(other)
AssertionError
```

Does it mean that variable c should not be a torch_tensor? After casting c to also be a FloatTensor gives the same error still.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I can't reproduce your error like that. What version of Pytorch are you using and how have you producing input_patch and c? Make sure that both c and input_patch are of the same dtype and are either both torch.autograd.Variable or both are common tensors. I suspect you might have made one a Variable and the other not? The line in your error is only to distinguish between having supplied a tensor as divisor or a constant as far as I know. As both is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input_patch is a slice of a torch.autograd Variable, and c is made by doing

```
c = torch.from_numpy(self.patch_filt[:, :, :, 0]).float()
```

Anyway, mexmex, thanks to your comment I've solved it by defining c as

```
Variable(torch.from_numpy(self.patch_filt[:, :, :, 0])).float()
```